# I want to upload the image to the database using default form in django but the image is not uploaded.It shows "No file chosen"

Tags: python, html, django

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Posts


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['topic','post','thumbnail','author']
```

**models.py**

```
class Posts(models.Model):
topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
post = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
thumbnail = models.ImageField()

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.post[:20]}..."

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'posts'
```

**views.py**

```
def add_post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("/")
else:
    form=PostForm()
context = {'form':form}
return render(request,'blog/add_post.html',context)
```

**add_post.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{% url 'blog:add_post' %}" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

    <input type='submit'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

when i try to submit the form the thumbnail field shows "no file chosen" automatically even when i have chosen the file.so please help me solve this issue!!!
[when i try to submit it shows "No file chosen" even when i chose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53juL.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add upload_to:

```
    item_image = models.ImageField(
        blank = True,
        null = True,
        upload_to = 'item/image/',
        db_column = 'ITEM_IMAGE',
        verbose_name = 'IMAGE',
    )
```

Remember to assign the path for mediafiles: (on settings.py)

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In forms.py:

```
    item_image = forms.ImageField(
        required = False,
        label = 'Image',
        widget = forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs = {'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 
        'IMAGE',}
        ),
    )
```

Here's my github with a django project to guide you:

[Github/Django](https://github.com/nouvellie/django3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your html form:

```html
 <form action="{% url 'blog:add_post' %}" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}

    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

And pass `request.FILES` to your form:

```py
def add_post(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect("/")
  else:
      form=PostForm()
  context = {'form':form}
  return render(request,'blog/add_post.html',context)
```

Comment: how did you learnt django?Can you tell me sources ,how did you learnt?

Comment: @Binay6014 I can recommend the book "Django 2 by Example", is a project based book so you will learn and put everything in practice at the same time.